# Why cant i pause the video when clicking the x on iframe

Tags: javascript, html

iam unable to pause/stop the video when X is pressed. when i click x the video still plays at the background.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0]; 

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
span.onclick = function() {
 modal.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
  modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<p style="margin: -5% 0;">
          <a id="myBtn" style="cursor: pointer;"><img src="someimages.jpg" /></a> pop up will appear upon clicking the image</p>
        <div id="myModal" class="modal">
          <!-- Modal content -->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close" onclick="testVids.pause();">&times;</span>
            <iframe id="testVids" controls src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe> </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with embedding YouTube videos, but two thoughts: A) Normally you can't access (I)Frames on other domains with JavaScript. B) If the included document isn't directly a video file  but HTML, then you can't use `pause()` on it.

Comment: Thanks! ive change it it jquery instead and it works. :)